# How to bind the HTML table with database using JavaScript or code behind

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, vb.net

I want to create one html table. that table contains 2 columns like teamName, TeamMember.

TeamName columns like label and Teammember columns like checkboxlist.

How to create and bind?

In aspx page my code like

```
<table id="table1" border="1" align="center">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    TeamName
                </th>
                <th>
                    TeamMember
               </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblbind" runat="server">
                   </asp:CheckBoxList>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

How to I bind these table?

In database my procedure:

```
alter procedure TeamBindingProc

@teamid as int

as

begin

select Teamid,TeamName from Team

    select UserId,TeamID,(select Nickname From [user] where [user].userid=TeamDetails.Userid)as Nickname from TeamDetails where Teamid=@teamid

end
```

Comment: Dim data As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim df As New DataTable
        Dim tr As New HtmlTableRow
        Dim td3 As New HtmlTableCell
        Dim td4 As New HtmlTableCell
        Dim lbl As New Label
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim cblbind As New CheckBoxList
        Dim strcon As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("KRGCbiz").ConnectionString
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(strcon)
        Dim CmdString As String = "select Teamid,teamname from team"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(CmdString, con)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you execute the stored procedure and fill it into the Dataset....and then you declare `<table id='table1' runat='server'>` and then on page load construct the HTML required for it using a string builder
like this

```
stingBuilder.Append("<tbody>");
stingBuilder.Append("<tr>");
stingBuilder.Append("<th>First Name</th>");
stingBuilder.Append("<th>Last Name</th>");

///more Html here as required by you

stingBuilder.Append("</tbody>");
```

and then at last append the stringbuilder to the table using

```
table1.innerHtml=stringBuilder.ToString();
```

also for dataBinding with JavaScript you can use AJAX call method, and you can return the same HTML through and in the success function. You can bind it to the table using the Id of it.

Comment: table1 is not shown in code bedind,, if i create dynamic means it will display otherwise??? then how to pass the parameter @teamId,,, how to bin label and checkboxlist at the time?...

Comment: have u declared it runat='server'...and if it is not showing u can use a <div runat='server' id='divTable'> and append the whole Html with table included in it...  divTable.InnerHtml=stingBuilder.ToString();

Comment: '<asp:table id="table1" runat="server"></table>' means 'table1' shown in code behind  '<table id="table1" runat="server" ></table> means it not shown..i tried but not shown..

Comment: '<asp:table id="table1" runat="server"></table>' means 'table1' shown in code behind '<table id="table1" runat="server" ></table> means it not shown..i tried but not shown..

Comment: just imagine one html table that table contains 2 column a and b,, a column have some name aaa,bbb, ccc that values in database..  these aaa , bbb, ccc have some members that members shown in column B check box list how i can do? cam u help me..

Comment: its shown... thank you i forget to type runat ="server" now its shown.. then nex how to bind it?

Comment: now coming then how to i bind.. i am the beginner so i tried so much but dont mine please can you help me

Comment: just imagine one html table that table contains 2 column a and b,, a column have some name aaa,bbb, ccc that values in database.. these aaa , bbb, ccc have some members that members shown in column B check box list how i can do? cam u help me

Comment: what ever ur html requirement is...type it using string builder every line of html u require this way.. stingBuilder.Append("<td>" + datatable.Rows[i]["FirstName"].ToString() + "</td>");

Comment: how to add that rows and display checkboxlist in html table ?

Comment: simple write the html for checkbox list <asp:CheckBoxList runat='server'>  ///list items and so on  </asp:CheckBoxList>

Comment: list items in database... if manually i put list item means i got... but items in database

Comment: actually items are in the database... how i can get that items then how to display those items in html table

Comment: <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblbind" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Sinthu"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="susi"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="siva"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:CheckBoxList> this type means easily get... but these names are in the database how i can get?

Comment: u have to use dataset for it...exectute the stored procedure and fill it into dataset through dataAdpater..

Comment: actually i fill dataset.. but only team name binding... team member not binding

Comment: in the select query where have u selected team member...??..select it then u can bind it..

Comment: i have two tables  team and teamdetails,, team table contains teamid and teamname(i used this select * from team for Bind team name), teamdetails table contains teamid,temmembername .. i created one procedure alter procedure TeamBindingProc                   

@teamid as int

as                    

begin

select UserId,TeamID,(select Nickname From [user] where [user].userid=TeamDetails.Userid)as Nickname from TeamDetails where Teamid=@teamid

end
this is used to bind checkbox list

Comment: in html table teamname binding team name displayed correctly but teammember not binding.. i dontknow how to bind teammember column through teamname column...

Comment: actually teamname like teamA,TeamB,TeamC,,, in TeamDetails table teamA contains siva,sinthu,robrt, TEAMB contains aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd ,ets...

Comment: how to i bind it? did You unterstand my pbm?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have a look at the *ListView* control. You can use it like this

```
    <asp:ListView runat="server">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="table1" border="1" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <th>TeamName
                    </th>
                    <th>TeamMember
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl1" Text='<%# Eval("ColumnNameOfYourTable") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblbind" runat="server">
                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

The datasource for the ListView can then be a SqlDataSource where you can use your sql query.

Comment: already i did that same concept in listview got output... need in html table